# How to fix Response body error '{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Scope must be specified"}'

Tags: rest, api, integration

Our client has given us their end point and when we are try to hit their API we are getting below Error

> '{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Scope must be
>   specified"}'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your API is not getting hit properly.Use Postman to call the API and enter the proper parameter.If your API is correct and you are passing the correct parameter it will work.

Comment: Please edit your answer and check the typos in your answer, for example "you api". also do not use "u" instead of "you'.